Do Interpolated Polynomials Approach Taylor Series?
Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function which is analytic on some open interval $I$. We can approximate $f$ with a degree-$n$ polynomial in two ways:

Take any point $x_0 \in I$ and compute its first $n$ derivatives. Then $f(x) \approx \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{f^{(i)}(x_0)}{i!}(x-x_0)^i$, most accurate near $x_0$.
Take $n+1$ points $x_0 ,\dots,x_n \in I$ and let $P(x)$ be the unique interpolating polynomial such that $P(x_i)=f(x_i)$ for $0 \leq i \leq n$. This is precise at at near the $x_i$, of course, but can go wild elsewhere.

Now letting $n \to \infty$, we know that as $f$ is analytic the Taylor series around $x_0$ will converge to $f$ in some neighborhood of $x_0$. But what about the interpolating polynomials?
Specifically, if we let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of points in $I$ and $P_n$ the $n$-th degree interpolating polynomial which agrees with $f$ at $x_0,\dots,x_n$, under what conditions do we have that $P_n \to f$ pointwise on some interval? Uniformly?

There is a fair amount of information here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation

Since the function might have a radius of convergence so that there is no Taylor series for all od the interval, but we can interpolate any unction so it works for all elements of the interval, no, it doesn't in any real reason to expect it to converge together as polynomials.
